# Outlook: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: .net, outlook, vsto, object-reference

I have an outlook add-in (basic pushing of mail to our app) which is returning an issue on one machine (works fine on others). It was just not working with no errors so we went to SYSTEM menu and turned VSTO_SUPPRESSDISPLAYALERTS = 0 to push to screen.

When I then ran the sync, I got the following

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.


************** Exception Text **************
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at MyAppOutlook.WaitingPopup.btnSyncOutlookInboxMail_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam,     IntPtr lparam)
```

I can't follow as to why this works on most machines but not this one. The plugin installs and appears on the toolbar for this machine like the others, it just doesn't work!

I have checked and reinstalled the following before I installed our plugin:

- .net3.5 Framework
- Primary Interop Assemblies 2007

n.b. Outlook is 2007.

**As requested, the code for the process is as follows**

```
Outlook.MAPIFolder outlookSentFolder =     (Outlook.MAPIFolder)outlookObj.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail);

for (int i = 1; i <= outlookSentFolder.Items.Count; i++)
{
    Outlook.MailItem mm = outlookSentFolder.Items[i] as Outlook.MailItem;
    if (mm != null)
    {
        try
        {
            DateTime StartDate = new DateTime(((Outlook.MailItem)outlookSentFolder.Items[i]).SentOn.Year, ((Outlook.MailItem)outlookSentFolder.Items[i]).SentOn.Month, ((Outlook.MailItem)outlookSentFolder.Items[i]).SentOn.Day, ((Outlook.MailItem)outlookSentFolder.Items[i]).SentOn.Hour, ((Outlook.MailItem)outlookSentFolder.Items[i]).SentOn.Minute, 0);

            if (StartDate > currentDate) // condition for current month mail sync
            {
                string attachs = "";
                for (int j = 0; j < ((Outlook.MailItem)outlookSentFolder.Items[i]).Attachments.Count; j++)
                {
                    attachs = ((Outlook.MailItem)outlookSentFolder.Items[i]).Attachments[j + 1].FileName.ToString() + "," + attachs;
                }

                ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
                string postData = "userDBName=" + subsDBName;
                postData += ("|MethodRequestName=addUpdateInboxMailFromOutlookToCRM");
                postData += ("|loginid=" + username);
                postData += ("|MailTo=" + ((Outlook.MailItem)outlookSentFolder.Items[i]).To);
                postData += ("|MailCC=" + ((Outlook.MailItem)outlookSentFolder.Items[i]).CC);
                postData += ("|MailFrom=" + ((Outlook.MailItem)outlookSentFolder.Items[i]).SenderEmailAddress);
                postData += ("|MailSubject=" + ((((((Outlook.MailItem)outlookSentFolder.Items[i]).Subject).Replace("|", "")).Replace("#", "")).Replace("<", "")).Replace(">", ""));
                postData += ("|MailBody=" + ((((((Outlook.MailItem)outlookSentFolder.Items[i]).Body).Replace("|", "")).Replace("#", "")).Replace("<", "")).Replace(">", ""));
                postData += ("|MailSentOn=" + StartDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"));//((Outlook.MailItem)outlookSentFolder.Items[i]).SentOn.ToString());
                postData += ("|MailType=Sent");
                postData += ("|MailAttach=" + attachs);
                byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

                // Prepare web request...
                HttpWebRequest myRequestSent = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(reqURL + "Views/Subscription/OutlookDataService.aspx");
                myRequestSent.Method = "POST";
                myRequestSent.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                myRequestSent.ContentLength = data.Length;
                Stream newStream = myRequestSent.GetRequestStream();
                // Send the data.
                newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                newStream.Close();

                WebResponse responseHtmlSent = myRequestSent.GetResponse();
                string xmlString = "";
                using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(responseHtmlSent.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    xmlString = xmlString + r.ReadToEnd();
                }
                responseHtmlSent.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Warning: " + ex.Message.ToString(), "Warning");
        }
    }
}
```

Please can anyone help as we have managed to get as far as getting this error? However, my understanding is that this error normally means we have incorrectly referenced the tables but then why would it work on most other machines?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the code for `btnSyncOutlookInboxMail_Click`? The error appears to be coming from that method.

Comment: Ok - code added above. Thanks

Comment: @pipsqueak: There's a lot of code there that could be the cause. Have you tried compiling a debug version? Or adding some debug statements? Without knowing the line number of the error, it will be hard to fix.

Comment: You say it doesn't work on 'one machine'. Are you sure it doesn't work on that machine or doesn't it work for one user? Because if it's user related it probably has something to do with how his/her mailbox is organized.

Comment: @MarkByers: Thanks for the reply. Yes, the big issue we have is that we can't get a location on the exact part of the code that is throwing the exception. The issue is that it is just this one user/machine that is having the issue rather than a straight-forward error. We run a version with debug statements but this exception is the only error we can generate on the screen which makes it frustrating

Comment: @Eddy: Thanks for the reply. My gut feeling is that it is user related but not sure how we can find out what it is that they have in their mailbox setup that is causing their issue... was just throwing it out there to see if anyone can suggest anything that we can look at in their setup that might be the cause when looking at our code

Comment: If you have trouble getting debug info go the oldfashioned way and add MessageBox.Show lines in there and see how far your code gets. Your code assumes that basically everything has a value set. I would not be surprised that if for instance a user drag/dropped an empty unsent mail to the sent items folder you would get a nullexception somewhere on any of those properties

Comment: Just noticed that the index for your attachments is doing item[j+1]. I didn't see in the docs that it was a 1 based index. I would guess that it is 0 based. In that case, if you have a mail with attachments then you will end up off the array. Unrelated to the error in your code, you could clean up a bunch `(Outlook.MailItem)outlookSentFolder.Items[i]` lines and replace them with `mm` since you assign `(Outlook.MailItem)outlookSentFolder.Items[i]` to `mm` at the top of the outer for loop.

Comment: @Eddy Thanks Eddy, will try this but think first call is to move this user onto another machine to find out if the issue is user related or machine related.

Comment: @pstrjds Good thinking but we have tested this on the user machine with simple text emails and no attachments so we know it can't *just* be related to that. Also, this is working for attachments for other users but will have another look at this to double check. Thanks for code clean too :-). I'll report back findings when we have moved user onto different machine

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the try...catch block into your code whilst you have been working on this problem or has it always been there?

If it has always been there and you mention that *It was just not working with no errors* then the errro must be outside of this.  I would check to see if the affected user does actually have a sent mail folder.